# Empty string added to string array when splitting for numbers

Tags: java, arrays, regex, split

I am currently trying to brush up on Java for university using codebat. My goal is to take a string of any ASCII characters, split all of the numbers from the string, then return the sum of all of the numbers as an int.

For example: `foo("abc123xyz")` should return 123 and `foo("12cd43ad")` should return 55

Here is my code:

```
public int sumNumbers(String str) {
  int sum = 0;
  
  String[] numArr = str.split("\\D+"); //This is my attempted regex
  for (String num: numArr) {
    sum += Integer.parseInt(num);
  }
  
  return sum;
}
```

When I run `sumNumbers("abc123xyz")` or `sumNumbers("aa11b33")`, I get this error:

`NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

Why is there an empty string in my numArr, and what is the proper regex to solve this issue?

Comment: Because you split with non-digits as separator, and this separator occurs at the beginning of the string. This behavior is also described in the documentation. Simple fix: wrap in an `if` statement: `if (!num.isEmpty()) { ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matcher is more applicable for this purpose then split:

```
int sum = 0;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while(m.find()) {
    sum+=Integer.parseInt(m.group());
}
return sum;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the following lines from the documentation of [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

> When there is a positive-width match at the beginning of this string
> then an empty leading substring is included at the beginning of the
> resulting array. A zero-width match at the beginning however never
> produces such empty leading substring.

You can confirm it by printing the resulting array. An empty string can not be parsed into an `int`. A workaround is to ignore the strings which can not be parsed into an `int`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(sumNumbers("abc123xyz"));
        System.out.println(sumNumbers("12cd43ad"));
    }

    public static int sumNumbers(String str) {
        int sum = 0;

        String[] numArr = str.split("\\D+");
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numArr));
        for (String num : numArr) {
            try {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(num);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // Ignore the strings which can not be parsed into int
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123
55
```

Answer (score 0):

You are splitting on the non-digits, unless the first character is a digit you're going to get a blank string, because it's the correct behavior according to the java doc
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-

Your function works fine on strings with digits as first characters.

Answer (score 0):

It may be needed to filter out the empty values after the `split("\\D+")` by non-digit sequences.

Also, stream API may be used to calculate the sum:

```java
public static int sumNumbers(String str) {
    return Arrays.stream(str.split("\\D+"))   // Stream<String>
                 .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())   // remove empty strings 
                 .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) // get IntStream (stream of primitive int)
                 .sum();
}
```

Test:

```
System.out.println(sumNumbers("abc123z-3yx"));   // 123 + 3
System.out.println(sumNumbers("12abc34z-6yx"));  // 12 + 34 + 6
```

Output:

```
126
52
```

---

Similarly, a pattern to match digit sequences `"-?\\d+"` (including optional `-?` to handle negative values) may be used:

```java
public static int sumNumbers(String str) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
    return p.matcher(str)
            .results()                   // Stream<MatchResult> since Java 9
            .map(MatchResult::group)     // get the matched sequence as string
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt) // get primitive int
            .sum();
}
```

Results for the same test data: (123 - 3) and (12 + 34 - 6)

```
120
40
```